# Can't I use unicode character properties in SAS?

Tags: regex, sas

I know the concept of `unicode character properties` from [this page](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/dfdmstudio/2.6/dmpdmsug/Content/DMCust_RegexLibUse.html).
I'm trying to use unicode character properties in SAS regular expression:

```
data test;
  input text &$42.;
  x=prxmatch('/\p{Han}/',text);
  put x=;
  cards;
  test
  43420
  测试
  テストします
;
run;
```

I get an error message:

```
ERROR: Use of \p{} or \P{} for wide characters is not supported in regex m/\p{Han}/.
```

Looking a way to fix it, thanks for any hints.
I'm using SAS® OnDemand for Academics, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would doubt it since this documentation page:
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p06i7305izsnvcn1ru9147suzyv5.htm says that it is only for use with Single Byte character sets.

**Restrictions:**   This function is assigned an I18N Level 0 status, and is designed for SBCS data. Do not use this function to process DBCS or MBCS data. For more information, see Internationalization Compatibility.

Comment: How will you do if you are asked to test a string contains chinese character or not? I tried `prxmatch('/[\u4E00-\u9FA5]/',text)` and failed.

Comment: If you want to test if any one of multiple specific multi-byte characters exist in a string then use the KINDEXC() function.